# I am not receiving email notifications

Tags: support

I am new to this site and I am not receiving email notifications for answers and comments to threads that I have subscribed to. I thought that I selected a check box to indicate that I wanted to receive email notifications when I first posted. I can't seem to find where to adjust this setting in the user section.

Answer (score 4):

You manage this by clicking on the 'preferences' link in your user profile. I checked your settings, and you've got it set to receive one daily email. The options are:

- Daily
- Every three hours

We don't do instant notifications; we'd rather that you stick around a while after posting and be available to address any comments asking for clarification or pointing out issues in something that you wrote.

Note, you'll get *unread* inbox notifications delivered, not *all* of them that you receive in the period that you select for notification. If you read the notification in your global inbox while using one of our sites, it won't be emailed to you later.

In short, if you *really* need to see an answer to something soon, keep the question page open and look for new answers appearing (you'll see them in real time). If you want to ask, then go get some lunch, work on some stuff, then check to see if you got any replies - set it to send you unread notifications every 3 hours.

If you just want a summary of what you missed after you walked away from your computer at the end of the day, set it to send unread notifications ever 24 hours.