# Notification on a response of my question

Tags: support

If I ask a question, sometimes the response is very fast on Stack Overflow. Sometimes I recieve multiple comments and answers within 1 hour. I respond to these, but after one hour there are hardly any responses any more.

So I would like to get notified for any response on my question. My e-mail address is known. I can not configure notifications.

As per ["How do comment @replies work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> "The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment."

But as per ["I am not receiving email notifications"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252817/i-am-not-receiving-email-notifications) there is something else

> "We don't do instant notifications; "

The suggestion asking to wait 3 hours sometimes does not work for me.
As I am doing other stuff, like programming, so I am not always active on Stack Overflow.

I know, that when I am logged in I can see notifications in the Stack Overflow inbox, but I am not always logged in.

I want to recieve notifications in my e-mail address inbox because that is always active for me. So I can respond faster to get the best answer.

Comment: A fast answer isn't necessarily the best answer. I tend to keep question I've asked open on a tab in my browser, for a few hours after asking them. It's really trivial to check for new replies, then.

Comment: I do agree. But sometime the person who answer miss a small detail from me. So if I could add that fast, the answer might be complete.

Comment: +1 I use my main mailbox as a one-stop shop for notifications, with many different things configured to send me e-mail. My phone beeps on incoming e-mail. I have mail open on each computer in my house... When I'm considering answering a question, but need some clarification first, I appreciate a quick response to a comment.

Comment: You get a notification in the top bar on any SO page. And live updates on the question page, which you should keep open anyways. If you ask a question and then close that tab or leave, you're doing it wrong - stay around and check the page at least every 5 minutes in the first half hour after asking. And definitely check at least once a minute in the first five minutes. If you don't have the time for that, you should probably not be asking questions.

Comment: As usual, @l4mpi hits the nail on the head.

Comment: I have that time, no problem. But the point is when somebody response is hard for me to predict. That is what notifications is about. But I understand this is choice of Stack Overflow. So I have to accept.